# Using multiple \multicolumn in a table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a table with 2 sets of data, each with the same type of measurements:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set A} \\
\cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set B} \\
\cline{3-4}
Weight& Diameter    & Weight &Diameter      \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

This code correctly places `Set A` over columns 1 and 2, but then it places `Set B` directly below `Set A`, also over columns 1 and 2. I cannot figure out how to specify which 2 columns that I want merged as the code just merges the first 2 (or 3, or however many are specified).

My second question is how to have separate `\cline`'s. I would like one to go over columns 1 and 2, and a distinct one to go over columns 3 and 4. Right now, they merge and I just see one line as if I had done `\hline`. This can be seen by commenting out `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set B} \\`

**Edit. May I ask how would I 'shift' the `\multicolun`'s? For example, if I had a common first row of dates, which neither `Set A` nor `Set B` should span, meaning `Set A` should span columns 2-3, and `Set B` should span columns 4-5.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are breaking it with

```
\\
\cline{1-2}
```

Put `&` instead and replace `\cline{3-4}` with `\hline`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set A} %%\\               %% <-- mistake
%% \cline{1-2}                               %% <-- mistake
&                                            %% <--  addition
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set B} \\\hline           %% <--  Changed
Weight& Diameter    & Weight &Diameter      \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> My second question is how to have separate \cline's

With `\clines`, you don't have much options but to have an additional column in the middle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c@{\quad}}{Set A}    
&&                                           
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set B} \\\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}          
Weight& Diameter    && Weight &Diameter      \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `booktabs` you have freedom:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c@{\quad}}{Set A}
&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set B} \\\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}
Weight& Diameter    & Weight &Diameter      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `(r)` in `\cmidrule(r){1-2}` says that line be trimmed from right side (`(l)` from left).

> May I ask how would I 'shift' the \multicolun's?.....

Just add one column in the beginning and change `\cline`s appropriately.

Without `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\hline
 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set A}
&&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set B} \\\cline{2-3}\cline{5-6}
Dates &Weight& Diameter    && Weight &Diameter      \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set A}
&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Set B} \\\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
Dates &Weight& Diameter    & Weight &Diameter      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]