# Grouping rows of an apa7 table by vertical line

Tags: tables, apa-style, booktabs, apa7

APA-style encourages grouping of columns with a horizontal line if needed, which I am doing with `\cmidrule(r){...}` in a `tabular` environment.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

Via this MWE I am using. (I am using `booktabs` following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155956/166234).)

```tex
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{sketchpad}
\author{Someone}
\date{Someday}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Some table}
  \label{tab:mytable}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lccccc@{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Datasets} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Sample characteristics} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-5}
  Name & Main measure & N participants & \% Female & Mean age \\ \midrule 
  First one & T1 & 111 & 11 & 10 \\
  Second one & T2 & 222 & 22 & 20 \\
  Third one & T3 & 333 & 33 & 30 \\
  Fourth one & T4 & 444 & 44 & 40 \\
   \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I need to group the rows as follows (the closest I could get to in MS Word) wherein the rows are grouped with vertical lines?

[image]

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment has a key `first-col` which I use here.

`nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the rows, columns and cells and it's possible to use these nodes to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter` after the construction of the array.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\shorttitle{}
\title{sketchpad}
\author{Someone}
\date{Someday}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Some table}
  \label{tab:mytable}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc@{}}[first-col]
  \toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Datasets} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Sample characteristics} \\
  \cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6}
   & Name & Main measure & N participants & \% Female & Mean age \\ \midrule
\Block{2-1}{\rotate Group A} & First one & T1 & 111 & 11 & 10 \\
 & Second one & T2 & 222 & 22 & 20 \\\addlinespace[1ex]
\Block{2-1}{\rotate Group B} & Third one & T3 & 333 & 33 & 30 \\
  & Fourth one & T4 & 444 & 44 & 40 \\
   \bottomrule
\CodeAfter 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw [shorten > = 4pt, shorten < = 4pt] (3-|1) -- (5-|1) ;
     \draw [shorten > = 4pt, shorten < = 4pt] (5-|1) -- (7-|1) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks. I compiled it over and over (on Overleaf, wit pdfLaTeX) but the horizontal lines do not appear, and also get this error `Package pgf Error: No shape named '1' is known.` 5 times (for `1`, `3`, `1`, `5`, `7`).

Comment: You have not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your installation. For Overleaf, you should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `bigdelim`, which comes with `multirow`:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigdelim, rotating}
\shorttitle{}
\title{sketchpad}
\author{Someone}
\date{Someday}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Some table}
  \label{tab:mytable}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}rccccc@{}}
  \toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Datasets} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Sample characteristics} \\
  \cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6}
   & Name & Main measure & N participants & \% Female & Mean age \\ \midrule
\ldelim|{2.2}{*}[\rotatebox{90}{\enspace\bfseries\footnotesize \makebox[0pt]{Group A}}] & First one & T1 & 111 & 11 & 10 \\
 & Second one & T2 & 222 & 22 & 20 \\\addlinespace[1ex]
\ldelim|{2.2}{*}[\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries\footnotesize \makebox[0pt]{\enspace Group B}}] & Third one & T3 & 333 & 33 & 30 \\
  & Fourth one & T4 & 444 & 44 & 40 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And how can I add the vertically written group names next to them?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I hadn't seen them. I'll fix that in a moment. Roughly, `\delim` accepts an optional argument for text on the left of `\ldelim`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is that better?

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible that the group names appear outside the table, such that the horizontal lines (of `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`) do go over and below it (like my second screenshot)?

Comment: @ManuHaq: You can do it with a hack: replace \midrule and \bottomrule with a `\cdmidrule{2-6}`with the relevant optional argument for thckness (respectively `[\lightrulewidth]` and `[heavyrulewidth]`, and  possibly the (l{some length})` argument for fine-tuning.

Comment: Thanks again. Let me just see if @F. Pantigny's solution (below) would work out more easily.